# Using Log4Net during setup application

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm having trouble seeing how I can use logging in my setup / install project.

I've got Log4net working on *installed* applications, but I can't seem to log the install / uninstall process.

My main problem is with the logging config file.
I suppose it's a bit of a chicken/egg scenario - theres no way for me to grab the just-installed logging file?

I have a method that finds the root directory of my app, using - AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase
and i normally use this to locate the logging config file.
This directory however, during install, is not where it is installing (obviously) it is somewhere within the windows filesystem.

Does anybody have any ideas to this?

Comment: never imagined that could log the setup with log4net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider configuring log4net in code and not using a file or storing the configuration as a file resource of your custom action assembly and using `XmlConfigurator.Configure(Stream configStream)` overload.

Of course if you want to reuse the configuration of the application this is not a clean solution.

Also checkout this question:

[log4net pure code configuration with filter in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885378/log4net-pure-code-configuration-with-filter-in-c)

Comment: I've basically created a "basicLogger" that, if the log4net.config file is not found, it uses an embedded resource config file, and just writes to c:\ drive... not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

When executing MSI's you are bound to msiexec's logging mechanisms (which is not as friendly as log4net).

Comment: in other words, it's impossible?

Comment: I mean, log4net is not supposed to be used with setup applications.

Comment: Impossible? No. But if you want log4net-like capabilities during an install, though, you'll have to write your own custom action(s) to do it. Like Otavio says, MSI's native logging leaves a lot to be desired.