# How to add a filter to log4net programmatically?

Tags: c#, log4net

Here is my attempt to set up log4net without using xml:

```
public class Logger
{
    public static void Setup()
    {
        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();           
        patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline";
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();
        RollingFileAppender roller = new RollingFileAppender();
        roller.AppendToFile = false;
        roller.File = @"Logs\EventLog.txt";
        roller.Layout = patternLayout;
        roller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 5;
        roller.MaximumFileSize = "1GB";
        roller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
        roller.StaticLogFileName = true;
        roller.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller);

        MemoryAppender memory = new MemoryAppender();
        memory.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(memory);

        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Info;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;
    }
}
```

Now I need to transform this xml-code:

```
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
    <stringToMatch value="error"/>
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
```

into my C#-code.
But the problem is I don't know how to use filter.
I can create a filter: `log4net.Filter.IFilter filter;` but `filter` doesn't provide [these](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.IFilter.html) options...

Could you please help to instert the filter into my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885378/log4net-pure-code-configuration-with-filter-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
...
RollingFileAppender roller = new RollingFileAppender();
roller.AppendToFile = false;
roller.File = @"Logs\EventLog.txt";
roller.Layout = patternLayout;
roller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 5;
roller.MaximumFileSize = "1GB";
roller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
roller.StaticLogFileName = true;

var filter = new log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter
{
    StringToMatch = "error",
    AcceptOnMatch = true
}
roller.AddFilter(filter);

var filterDeny = new log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter();
roller.AddFilter(filterDeny);
...
```